# Change equity order in etrade api?

Tags: etrade-api

Does anyone know how to change an equity order utilizing the etrade API? I can do place order just fine but for some reason changing an equity order seems impossible! I have poured over the documentation and have failed at understanding how to do it.... I keep on getting a 9999 error

https://apisb.etrade.com/docs/api/order/api-order-v1.html#/definition/orderPreview

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get it to work either. I printed the errors and reason codes

```
https://api.etrade.com/v1/accounts/{myaccountkey}/orders/76/change/preview
<Response [405]>
Method Not Allowed
<Error>
  <code>9999</code>
</Error>
```

405 isn't documented, and 9999 says `The service you requested is not available at this time. Please try again.`

Probably best to cancel and reenter the order, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you're seeing usually comes with the message "Message Not Allowed".

The problem that you're seeing might be happening because when you place an order you have to use the HTTP POST method, but when you're changing an order you have to use the HTTP PUT method. You might want to check that you're using the correct method when you change an order.